# The equality of fermi energy and chemical potential at high temperatures

Tags: statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

Through the duration of my equilibrium statistical mechanics course, I came across a point in ideal Fermi systems where the Fermi energy was approximated as chemical potential when we derive the expression for energy from the density of states. So my question is that though the approximation would work well at low temperatures, how does it explain the characteristics at temperatures that are high enough to not satisfy the approximation of $\epsilon_F=\mu$?

Comment: Ashcroft and Mermin cover the difference early on.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: In A&M, it is a fairly dense set of equations to go through in Chapter 2 where one finds (eq 2.77 in my edition) that the chemical potential is slightly different from the (T=0) Fermi energy.